# How to make a SLAM robot using Lidar and Raspberry Pi 3 from scratch

Tags: slam, navigation, lidar, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there, I have to make an autonomous slam robot that will make a map of the environment and navigate through it automatically, I'm totally new at ROS and I need to know that how to do this project and what to do at first place.( like make a map at first then how to make a map?)
I'm stuck at the start. I don't know how to start and where to start I have to order the equipment too that would be Lidar and raspberry pi 3, would it be right or not?
also, tell me the odometer sensor that would be right?
it'll be great if you guide me rightly.

Thank you,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276200/how-to-make-a-slam-robot-using-lidar-and-raspberry-pi-3-from-scratch/) by [Hassam](https://answers.ros.org/users/32669/hassam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This project is not an easy one. However it is very funny.
First of all I strong recommend you to do all the tutorials to get some basic knowledge about R.O.S.
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials

After that I think you have to concentrate in the navigation stack.
http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials

Finally I think this is a great tutorial also and exactly what you need
http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_gazebo/Tutorials/indigo/Make%20a%20map%20and%20navigate%20with%20it

It is better to try in a simulated environment (i.e. Gazebo) and then, after doing all of this you will know exactly what hardwarde you need to buy.

best,

---

Originally posted by [fandrade](https://answers.ros.org/users/26822/fandrade/) with karma: 81 on 2017-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0